# Passing JS getCurrentPosition to global variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, geolocation, global-variables

I am building an app that requires user location, to achieve this i am using:

```
var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    console.log('Your current position is:');
    console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
    console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
    console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
    console.log(` ${crd.longitude}`);
 }

function error(err) {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    console.log(`Latitude : 9`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

How can i pass the user lattitude and longitude to a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **local storage** for an optimize solution.

```
var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    console.log('Your current position is:');
    console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
    console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
    console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
    let userLatitude = crd.latitude;
    let userLongitude = crd.longitude;
    localStorage.setItem("USER_LATITUDE", userLatitude);
    localStorage.setItem("USER_LONGITUDE", userLongitude);
    console.log(` ${crd.longitude}`);
 }

function error(err) {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    console.log(`Latitude : 9`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

If you want to use this location data;

```
var latitude = localStorage.getItem('USER_LATITUDE');
var longitude = localStorage.getItem('USER_LONGITUDE');
```

Answer (score 1):

declare your variables globally and assign them in the callback... (global vars are not good practice)

```js
window.userLat = null;
window.userLng = null;

var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
  console.log(` ${crd.longitude}`);
  userLat = crd.latitude;
  userLng = crd.longitude;
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
  console.log(`Latitude : 9`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Comment: thanks @Argee for your replay. i tried the snippet but the global variable returned null.Thanks again.